# Multiple applications and environments with angular-cli

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I working on huge angular2 application, and i looking for solution how to handle this case:

So my application is 7 applications in one source code, in previous version of application written in angular1 I specify which platform and env in this way:

```
gulp build --platform=platform1/platform2/platform3 --env=dev/staging/uat/prod
```

Basically I need a solution to choose {platformName}.main.ts based on parameters from command line, as a starting point. I need this parametrization also for unit and e2e tests.

How to do that using angular-cli? 
Is it possible without custom webpack configuration? 
Maybe it will be better to use clean webpack for this case?

Answer (score 0):

AngularCli uses already Webpack. I was looking for something like that so I found out that we can configure `.angular-cli.json` to set multiple apps in `apps` array and same thing with the list of environments in each app.
See more in this [blog] : https://yakovfain.com/2017/04/06/angular-cli-multiple-apps-in-the-same-project/

Hope that help you

Comment: this works fine for development. But building with `ng build --app=app1 --prod` fails. It tries to take the `AppModule` from all the apps. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Did you try `ng build –app=app1 –aot` ? Can you print the message error ? It could be some config issue about the compiler !